# Passing array of arrays as props

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here....

```
<Something
content={[
    {
        heading: "Add Company",
        icon: "plus",
        options: {[
            {
                image: "srcimage",
                text: "New Company",
                link: "test"
            }, {  //Errors here
                image: "srcimage",
                text: "Existing Company",
                link: "test"
            }
        ]}
    }, {
        heading: "Import Company",
        icon: "download",
        options: {[
            {
                image: "/src/image",
                text: "Class",
                link: "/test"
            },
            {
                image: "/src/image",
                text: "BGL",
                link: "/test"
            },
            {
                image: "/src/image",
                text: "SuperMate",
                link: "/test"
            }
        ]}
    }]
} />
```

I get the error... `Unexpected token, expected "]"` where it says `error here`. Eventually I would like to create some blocks of content based on whats passed in like this....

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{[]}` isn't valid syntax for an object.

```
content={[
  {
    heading: "Add Company",
    icon: "plus",
    options: [ // remove the curly boy that was here
      {
        image: "srcimage",
        text: "New Company",
        link: "test"
      }, { 
        image: "srcimage",
        text: "Existing Company",
        link: "test"
      }
    ] // and here
  }, {
    heading: "Import Company",
    icon: "download",
    options: [ // and here
      {
        image: "/src/image",
        text: "Class",
        link: "/test"
      },
      {
        image: "/src/image",
        text: "BGL",
        link: "/test"
      },
      {
        image: "/src/image",
        text: "SuperMate",
        link: "/test"
      }
    ] // and here
  }]}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the options properties you need to remove the curly braces, just pass the array

```
options: [
  {
    image: "srcimage",
    text: "New Company",
    link: "test"
  }, 
  {
    image: "srcimage",
    text: "Existing Company",
    link: "test"
  }
]
```